# How to keep both text layout format and text font from PDF?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to extract text from pdf with keeping layout and font style format using Pdfbox

I'm using Pdfbox version 2.0.16

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.tools.PDFText2HTML;

import io.github.jonathanlink.PDFLayoutTextStripper;

 try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("filpath.pdf"));// ..... Read PDF file
            PDDocument pdd = PDDocument.load(is); //This is the      in-memory representation of the PDF document.
            PDFText2HTML converter = new PDFText2HTML(); // the converter

            String html = converter.getText(pdd); // html but lost layout

            String text =    new PDFLayoutTextStripper().getText(pdd); // layout but lost font style


            pdd.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // ......
        }
```

i expected html result keeping layout format?

Comment: There is no such feature in PDFBox. You could try to create this yourself (lots of work!) based on the PrintTextLocations.java example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to extract font. To read font one has to iterate through pdf pages and extract font as below:

```
PDDocument  doc = PDDocument.load("C:/mydoc3.pdf");
List<PDPage> pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
for(PDPage page:pages){
    Map<String,PDFont> pageFonts=page.getResources().getFonts();
}
```

Comment: sorry it's not about to extract font only, i need to extract font and keep all spaces on the layout.
getting fonts will not keep layout as it's

Comment: get the position of the text. that's will solve your prb